# Regular Expression | Formatting Number in a text filed at my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using regular expression to format numbers in a text field, I have achieved the the functionality that a comma is inserted after every 3 digits like the following

- 123 -> 123
- 1234 -> 1,234
- 123456->123,456

I am using the following function to achieve this.

```
function Comma(Num) { //function to add commas to textboxes
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        console.log(x);
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        console.log(x1);
        console.log(x2);
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{2})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        console.log("x1: "+x1);
        return x1 + x2;
    }

<input maxlength="" class="form-control preco number" name="preco[]" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" required>
```

What i want to achieve is the below format

- 12->12
- 123 -> 1,23
- 1234 -> 12,34
- 123456->1.234,56

Can you guide me how can i achieve this format using regular expressions??

Comment: Could you explain your wanted format a bit better? What's the rule for placing a `.` and `,`? And what would `12345678` and `123456789` be?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek a `,` is placed after 2 digits and then a `.` is placed after every 3 digits. it would be 123.456,78 and 1.234.567,89 !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$
```

result

```
1
12
.99
12.34 
-18.34
12,345.67
999,999,999,999,999.99
```